# how to make app exampl linux write command

Tags: android

How to create an Android application that uses a command line like Linux

It can be scripted for some commands from the user and is implemented such as showing files or entering a folder of what the recipients are

Comment: have a look at [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app)

Comment: @tuna-mcfish yes >> how to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
try {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ls");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, using :

```
String commandLine = "ping google.com"
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
```